# Who restores the hibernation image on disk?

Tags: suspend, hibernate, resume

guys,
I'm doing experiment on ubuntu 14.04.2, and try to figure out who is responsible for resuming the system from hibernation.

In order to track it, I add some dump_stack in software_resume, which is in kernel code, and to my surprise, there is a process called 'resume' that has 
stored a device(major:minor) number into /sys/kernel/resume, which brings the system back from hibernation.

So I searched through the Internet, and found that, there is a package called uswsusp that is used for initrd to restore the system. Then I dig into the code
of uswusp(suspend-utils-1.0) and found that there is actually a resume.c in the code. However when I looked through this file I can not find anything about how to write (major:minor) pairs to /sys/kernel/resume.

Can any body here please tell me how ubuntu restore the hibernation by using 
'resume' process?
thank you in advance.